# How to know if MATERIALIZED VIEW update is running?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm talking about oracle. I have a few materialized views, and they're updated from time to time (it is done with a scheduled task). It is easy to know last refresh date - just query  USER_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES.
And is there any way to know if some views are being updated in the current moment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could see indirectly if a materialized view is being refreshed by looking if a process has aquired locks on it : a materialized view should be modified only when refreshed (except FOR UPDATE materialized views used for two-way replication).

This query should return rows only when your materialized view is being refreshed:

```
SELECT sid
  FROM v$lock
 WHERE type = 'TX'
   AND id1 = (SELECT object_id
                FROM all_objects
               WHERE owner = :owner
                 AND object_name = :object_name)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could try:

`SELECT CURRMVOWNER, CURRMVNAME FROM V$MVREFRESH`

to get the list of views refreshing right now.

Answer (score 5):

Materialized views that are defined to be refreshed on a schedule with "... START WITH... NEXT..." as part of their DDL will be executing under DBMS_JOB control.  If the refresh of these MV's is in progress, you'll see values for THIS_DATE and THIS_SEC in the USER_JOBS (or DBA_JOBS) view for the corresponding job and/or a row in DBA_JOBS_RUNNING.

If you've defined the MV to be refreshed on demand and are launching the refresh externally then Vincent's answer is one way to determine the state.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But views are updated with external java task.